# How to update an array within object with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update a state object. One of the items is a key whose value is an array of strings.

I've been able to update the state, but it does not rerender.

```
const initialState = {
  showUpload: false,
  listItems: parentDirs,
  uploadPath: [],
  fileList: null
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "updateListItems":
      return { ...state, listItems: action.payload };
    case "updatePath":
      return {
        ...state,
        uploadPath: [...state.uploadPath, action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const pathFormat = state.uploadPath.join('/')

return (
 <p>{pathFormat}</p>
)
```

The expected behavior would be that updating the array within the state object would trigger a rerender.

Comment: Would you provide how you call the dispatch as well as the rendered elements? (in `return`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure as to why your component is not rerendering, since you didn't show how it is working. So, what I did, and suggest you do for further questions, is building a minimum, reproducible example on which to test the code. This way, we can see how you are attempting to solve your problem, and see the error in its context.

For React projects, I like to use `CodeSandbox`. [Here is the link to my example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-swanson-ik80g)

As people in the comments have mentioned, I believe the problem you are having is with the way you are dispatching the actions. On the example, I show two ways to modify an array. On the first one, you handle all the login inside the component, and end up dispatching the full new array on the `action payload`. Then on the `reducer`, you have to replace the current one with the new.

On the second example, I dispatch a new value to be included on the array. The `reducer` is now in charge of modifying the `state`.

Where is the best place to handle this logic? It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If the logic is going to be shared by multiple components, then you could centralize it in the reducer. But, if different components are going to handle those arrays differently, then decentralizing the logic could be the way to go.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But this makes useReducer pointless... this is extremely convoluted... there is literally no reason to use `useReducer` in your example....

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely sure what lives inside that array, but here's an example that might help.

The thing you need is an identifier to target. Lets say you have the following:

```js
state = {
cats: [
 {
  name: 'cat1',
  id: 1
 },
  name: 'cat2',
  id: 2
 }
],
// ... rest of state

}
```

To override cat 2, you'd do something like:

```js
//           action.type           action.payload
dispatch({ type: 'updateCats', payload: {id: 2, name: 'cat3' }})

// ... and your reducer's switch returns:
case 'updateCats':
  return {
    ...state,
    cats: [...state.cats.filter( cat => id !== payload.id), action.payload]
}
```

You need to rebuild the array by removing the old item and adding it again. How you do this is up to you. You can either slice & splice, or if order isn't important the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method used in the example should work.

Answer (score 2):

***Edit:*** I think I see what you are trying to do, and have updated my answer to reflect what I think I see - please let me know if this is what you're looking for..

You are close! Just need to change how you are using `dispatch` as well as use the spread operator on `action.payload` inside of the reducer... Although, it is unclear if you are using a "flat" array, or an array of objects - my example shows the "easy" way, using a "flat" array...

Something like this should work:

```js
const initialState = {
  showUpload: false,
  listItems: "parentDirs",
  uploadPath: ["original","paths"],
  fileList: null
};

const TYPES = {
  UPDATE_LIST_ITEMS: "UPDATE_LIST_ITEMS",
  UPDATE_PATH: "UPDATE_PATH",
  JOIN_PATHS: "JOIN_PATHS"
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TYPES.UPDATE_LIST_ITEMS:
      return { 
        ...state, 
        listItems: action.payload 
      };
    case TYPES.UPDATE_PATH:
      return {
        ...state,
        uploadPath: [...state.uploadPath, ...action.payload]
      };
    case TYPES.JOIN_PATHS:
      return {
        ...state,
        joinedPaths: state.uploadPath.join("/")
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


function Example(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  
  const changeUploadPath = () => {
    dispatch({type: TYPES.UPDATE_PATH, payload: ["some", "new", "paths"]})
  }
  
  const joinUploadPaths = () => {
    dispatch({type: TYPES.JOIN_PATHS});
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={joinUploadPaths}>Join Upload Paths</button>
      <button onClick={changeUploadPath}>Change Upload Path</button>
      <p>{state.joinedPaths}</p>
      <br />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```